# Importing Simplified Chinese text from CSV into SQLite database

Tags: csv, sqlite, cjk

I have a working SQLite database file.  I have a .CSV file containing 3 cols - ID, english, chinese.  The chinese text is encoded in GB2312.  The file is UTF8 with BOM.  When I use the import option in SQL Lite Database Browser, I get gibberish for the chinese.  What do I do to fix this?  I tried taking out the BOM -- no good.

Comment: I got the answer.  Use the Firefox extension. http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. -- Use the Firefox extension

http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Some of the older versions of the SQLite Database Browser only supported UTF8.

As you seen, you need to use a different method to load the data